# Should Matlab questions be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

This question:

- https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2141/8

asks about recommendation of the approach using a set of data in Matlab learner app.

Do you think such question should be on-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that specific question is off topic, and migrated it to Cross Validated. (As I understood it, had two parts--first, does Matlab's learner do bootstrapping, and second, is there a problem with doing bootstrapping twice, neither of which strike me as deeply relevant for AI.)

For machine learning questions, I'm mostly looking at whether the question is 1) well-understood and 2) relevant to the conceptual, social, or philosophical aspects of AI. The closer it is to a statistical issue, the more likely it is to go to Cross Validated, and the closer it is to a data or programming issue, the more likely it is to go to Data Science or Stack Overflow.

I don't think that the question is about Matlab is relevant except that questions that hinge on a particular language are likely to end up as being too close to programming to fit here.